# how use several variables in one v-text

Tags: vue.js

I want to use several variables in one v-text.

Tried code:

```
<p v-text="mnb.name mnb.address"></p>
```

But this not works. How can I use v-text for show several data?

Comment: most probably what you need is `v-text="\`${p1} ${p2}\`"`

Comment: @Sphinx this works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to concat two strings with one space.

So the solution is

```
v-text="`${p1} ${p2}`"
```

**or** `v-text="p1 + ' ' + p2"`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      p1: '123',
      p2: 'abc'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-text="`${p1} ${p2}`"></p>
  <p v-text="p1 + ' ' + p2"></p>
</div>
```